# My "Next page" button still keeps the previous pages information, and it looks messy

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I need to test out the rest of my `WPF application` but cannot navigate through it, whenever I try navigate to the **Next page** my application still shows the information from the **previous page** on top of it. What other way can I navigate through my page's, I have 3 in total. I've tried this way of navigating pages:

```
private void Btn_1_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Main.Navigate(new DatePicker());
   this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use MVVM desing partner.

Someting like this:

https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/

Because Model-View-ViewModel architecture can be over overcomplicated to write, there is handy tools like this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio

That actually generate MVVM architecture for you.